# Is there any way to get a key I no longer have access to deleted from the keyserver?

Tags: pgp, keyserver

The file was overwritten when I reformatted my hard drive. There are now 2 keys under my name registered on the site. I can prove I *had* access to the key, but I need to know where to ask for removal, or even if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to delete keys from key servers. You could revoke it with a revocation certificate created in advance or access to the private key (to create such one), but never delete a key.

Well, theoretically you could, but you'd have to convince each single administrator of one of the hundreds of OpenPGP key servers to do so, and if somebody uploads it again it will reappear and redistribute. Most of these administrators will refuse anyway.

---

To prevent loosing access to your key, do following:

1. Regularly backup your computer (important anyway).
2. Create an offline copy of your private keys.
3. Create a revocation certificate *immediately* after creating a primary key. Store it both in a digital way and print it on a piece of paper (I recommend something like `gpg --gen-revoke | qrencode` to be able to scan the certificate without the hassles of OCR).
4. Create a second copy and hand it to somebody you trust. He cannot do anything but revoke your keys with it (never gain access!), but you always have a fall-back in worst case scenarios (house burned, robbery, ...).